# How to politely say my plans have changed, and I can now catch up for a quick meeting

Tags: meetings

***Addendum:*** I am in Vietnam from Australia on a 2 week business trip. I came here to meet with Company A, which I did on my first week of coming up here (last week Friday). Four days after meeting (Tuesday), the Founder emailed me the following e-mail:

---

> *Hi 3kstc,*
>
> *Are you still here until Friday this week? What is a good time to catch up with each other?*

to which I (naively) replied:

> *Hi Mr.X*
>
> *I trust you’re well. 
>   I'm fully committed over the next 2-3 nights before I fly out, but would love to catch up on my next visit.*
>
> *Kind Regards,*

My plans have changed, and thereby now I am able to meet up, especially since I don't have to come in to work on Saturday and go directly to the Airport.

---

***TL;DR:*** *My plans have changed, now I'm able to meet up.*

**Q:** How would I professionally and politely phrase this?

Comment: Be honest?  Reach out saying your plans have changed and if the offer is still available, you'd like to get together.

Comment: What's your thinking on why what you'd say ordinarily would be considered impolite?

Comment: i'm just thinking there might be a more amicable way of saying "My plans have changed". - or maybe I'm just naive and over thinking it :/

Comment: It's not clear what the relationship here is. Are they your boss, future employer, underling, non work person? You are overthinking this: your e-mail you mentioned was polite, so just follow that same kind of style and mention something's changed and you'd love to catch up now.

Comment: @Tas Sorry Tas, I've added to give the over all picture - email was received from the founder of a company of which we want do business with.

Comment: Have a beer with the founder, it's a business meeting not just a catch-up.

Comment: I think it's more a of [formal] business meeting in an informal setting....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make this into a positive and highlight your successes.

> Hi Mr X, I hope you're well.
>
> I've had some really successful meetings with my clients, which have  concluded early.  I now have some time before I leave on Saturday, are you still ok to meet with me?

Then go on to mention your free periods.

The key thing here is that you're promoting yourself as a success in getting your meetings successfully concluded early, and this should send a positive message to the founder.  You're also giving him a reason as to why your plans have suddenly changed.

Comment: I seriously need more mentors like you

Comment: The only additional comment I'd make here: avoid adverbs (like "really") since they're intended to express degree. You shouldn't be the one saying that the meetings were really successful; the client should. 

Consider instead something like, "My clients and I reached a successful conclusion sooner than we expected, so I've now got some time available <days and times>. Would it be convenient for us to meet then?"

Answer (score 3):

> Hi Mr. X
>
> sorry for the short notice, but my plan are changed and I might be able to meet you before my departure on Saturday if you still have time in your agenda.
>   I am available on ..
>
> kind regards

Business people should know that agendas are living creatures constantly changing, so don't overthink it.